# Symfony 5 - OneToMany does not appear in my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony4, symfony5

So I have two tables : one is "cable" -> the main one AND the other one is "color"

So i created an entity inside cable called colors linked to the color table with the OneToMany relation.
But the problem is that the migration:migrate does not appear in my database when the other ManyToOne relation does.

Here it what's inside my migration.php file :

`

```
final class Version20210411225338 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE cables DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_9A9430025ED47289');
       $this->addSql('DROP INDEX IDX_9A9430025ED47289 ON cables');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE cables DROP couleurs_id');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE colors ADD cables_id INT NOT NULL');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE colors ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C2BEC39F4DE1706A FOREIGN KEY (cables_id) REFERENCES cables (id)');
       $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_C2BEC39F4DE1706A ON colors (cables_id)');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE cables ADD couleurs_id INT NOT NULL');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE cables ADD CONSTRAINT FK_9A9430025ED47289 FOREIGN KEY (couleurs_id) REFERENCES colors (id)');
       $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_9A9430025ED47289 ON cables (couleurs_id)');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE colors DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_C2BEC39F4DE1706A');
       $this->addSql('DROP INDEX IDX_C2BEC39F4DE1706A ON colors');
       $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE colors DROP cables_id');
    }
}
```

`
My Cable.php file :

`

```
/**
  * @return Collection|Colors[]
  */
    public function getCouleurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->couleurs;
    }

    public function addCouleur(Colors $couleur): self
    {
        if (!$this->couleurs->contains($couleur)) {
           $this->couleurs[] = $couleur;
           $couleur->setCables($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCouleur(Colors $couleur): self
    {
        if ($this->couleurs->removeElement($couleur)) {
           // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
           if ($couleur->getCables() === $this) {
           $couleur->setCables(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Colors::class, mappedBy="cables")
  */
    private $couleurs;
```

`

And my colors.php file :

`

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Cables::class, mappedBy="couleurs")
  */
    private $cables;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cables = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use `php bin/console make:entity` from the maker bundle, when you add your color field, say it's a relations it will help make you the code and you can read how it work after

Answer (score 2):

You have `OneToMany` on both sides, that doesn't work.
I think you mean to do `ManyToMany` where `Colors` can be referenced by many `Cables` and a `Cable` can have many `Colors`.

Since you have a collection on each side and you manage the relation from `Cable`, You should have a [many-to-many-bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) relation with `Cable` as the owning side. Try adjusting your mapping as follows.

Cable:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Colors::class, inversedBy="cables")
   * @JoinTable(name="cables_colors")
   */
  private $couleurs;
```

Colors:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Cables::class, mappedBy="couleurs")
   */
  private $cables;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in my mind : One product can have multiple colors. This is why I used OneToMany, why choose ManytoMany then ?

Comment: Are the `Colors` entities exclusively related to that one `Cable` instance, or are they reused by multiple `Cable` entities?

Comment: In my mind, if more than one product can come in "blue" then you create the "blue" entity once and share (ManyToMany). A OneToMany means that each product will have its own duplicated "blue" entity.

Comment: I don't know if I explain it well, one cable can be blue and red and black. This is why I used OneToMany. Sorry for my late responses...

Comment: If you want your colors to be unique to a product (meaning that the color blue for instance could be duplicated in your database) then you are ok with a OneToMany, but the other side HAS to be ManyToOne and you will need a mappedBy on one side and an inversedBy on the other side (the owning side should have the inversedBy). If you do not intend to have duplicated colors, then you will most likely want to use a ManyToMany.